# Stop swal loading on success ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert2

I'm using sweetalert2 to pop up a dialog where users will input a pin.
The problem I'm facing is that I want to stop the button clicked from loading when the ajax request is completed.

So far I've used

```
Swal.hideLoading() ;
```

And

```
Swal.stopLoading();
```

But it doesn't stop the loader

```
swal.fire({
    title : "Confirm Transfer! ", 
    html :  "Enter pin" ,
    icon : "warning", 
    input : "text", 
    confirmButtonText: 'Confirm', 
    showLoaderOnConfirm: true, //show button loader 
    preConfirm: (pin) => {
        return new Promise(function (resolve) { 
            $.ajax({
            //ajax request
                success:function(data) {
                    Swal.stopLoading(); // stop button from loading and return to default button text value
                } 
            })
        })
    }
})
```